# Is Windows susceptible to the ARP flux issue?

Tags: windows, networking, arp

I have a test setup where a device is connected through an (integrated) Ethernet switch to a multiple Network interfaces PC running Linux.

The goal of this setup is to test all the interfaces with IPerf3.

I soon discovered about the [ARP Flux problem](https://shradha741.medium.com/the-arp-flux-problem-3a4c92157f79) in Linux. This problem causes traffic that should be flowing through one interface to go to another one. Anyway, [this was easily solved once I knew what the problem was](https://serverfault.com/a/834519).

Now, the guy who's actually testing the device runs a PC with Microsoft Windows 10. I tried searching various "Windows" and "ARP Flux" terms on the Internet but couldn't find neither a positive nor a negative answer. I thus don't know if I have to take any precautionary action against it when running a Windows Machine.

1. Is Windows also susceptible to the same problem? If yes, what is the name of it in Microsoft's ecosystem?
2. How can I configure Windows to avoid the problem from happening?

Comment: This should be easy enough to test, “ A Linux host that has many Ethernet interfaces on the same subnet is subject to the ARP Flux problem. The ARP Flux problem occurs when a host replies to ARP requests for interfaces on the same subnet, from any interface on that same subnet.”, just need a Windows host with multiple Ethernet adapters assigned to the same subnet. Have you done that?

Comment: It is not deterministic. Even on Linux, the traffic may be flowing all on the respective interface until an ARP request is replied on the "wrong" interface. So, to avoid Murphy's Law, I prefer to have a strong "yes" or "no".

Comment: It is nevertheless easy enough to test, without relying on any real traffic flow: send out an ARP query for a Windows system's address A, check whether you receive only one ARP reply (from MAC address A) or whether you receive two (from both MAC addresses A and B). It doesn't matter which reply arrives first (the non-deterministic "ARP flux" problem), only whether the unwanted replies are being sent out at all (which is deterministic, either the OS does it or doesn't).